# How does expansion of the skin via mitosis influence the density of its specialised nerve endings

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, skin

I found a reddit question [Do nerves & nerve endings expand with skin or does skin expansion causes loss of nerve density](https://www.reddit.com/r/biology/comments/ckmxd9/do_nerves_nerve_endings_expand_with_skin_or_does/) where a user references the study [Assessment of Epidermal Nerve Fibers: A New Diagnostic and Predictive Tool for Peripheral Neuropathies](https://academic.oup.com/jnen/article/66/12/1059/2916709) which states that intraepidermal nerves fiber density is not dependent on weight

> No significant relationship of race, height, or weight on IENF density has been reported

Reasoning that if additional nerves are not generated in response to expansion of the skin, then one should expect a negative relationship between nerve density and weight.

My question is, upon expansion via mitosis, will sensitive skin rich in specialised nerve endings such as the Meissners corpuscles generate more of this same type of nerve endings?

Specifically i’m curious about the inner foreskin and innervation of new tissue created under [foreskin restoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreskin_restoration) if that makes a difference

> Foreskin restoration is the process of expanding the skin on the penis
> to reconstruct an organ similar to the foreskin, which has been
> removed by circumcision or injury. Foreskin restoration is primarily
> accomplished by stretching the residual skin of the penis